# PHP output all Python console output to browser

Tags: php, python

I am running a script from here: https://github.com/PokemonGoF/PokemonGo-Bot

The script outputs all the information to the console, but I want to output it to my browser using PHP.

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
// Turn off output buffering
ini_set('output_buffering', 'off');
// Turn off PHP output compression
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', false);

ob_implicit_flush(true);ob_end_flush();
$cmd = 'python pokecli.py';
//$cmd = 'python test.py';
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),   // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),   // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
   2 => array("pipe", "w")    // stderr is a pipe that the child will write to
);
flush();
$process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, realpath('./'), array());
echo "<pre>";
if (is_resource($process)) {
    while ($s = fgets($pipes[1])) {
        print $s;
        flush();
    }
}
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

I am not getting any output and also no errors in my NGINX logs.

*I have looked at all of the similar questions and none of the answers worked*

Comment: I assume, as long as you don't provide the correct (or any) parameters to the python script, it'll just write to stderr (because it's all errors). Have you tried reading from stderr? ^^ Also by "I am not getting any output" - do you mean besides the `<pre></pre>`? You should probably add some output inside the `if(is_resource($process))`

Comment: @Jakumi How do I read from stderr?
The only output I am getting is `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`

Comment: when you fgets($pipes[1]) you read from stdout, with 2 you would from stderr. **However**, since you're not getting the `<pre></pre>` - which should be output according to your code, no matter what the process does - are you sure the php code is actually run? ^^ or you don't flush enough afterwards. As long as you don't get the <pre> there's something wrong outside the process as well.